# Best way to search function in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, search-engine

I have a search function on my website implemented with elasticsearch.
Now I have a little question about design.

I have a `searchAction` with route `/search` that takes a parameter in the query string. Like `/search?terms=...`.

I would like to make the results list filterable, but I have some doubts about the right design to achieve this.

What is the best solution to make a list of filtered results?

If I pass the filter parameter I need to specify a form action with the current url and append the current query string like a link, right?
Example:

```
<form action="{{ current_pat }} ~ {{ query_string }}" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter_one">....
```

In this case the url will like: `/search?terms=...` and in `$post` I have the filter. Is this the right solution, or is a list of links better?
Example:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="{{current_path}} ~ {{ query_string }} ~ {{ this_filter }}">... 
    <li><a href="{{current_path}} ~ {{ query_string }} ~ {{ this_another_filter }}">
...
```

In this case the url will be like: `/search?terms=...&this_filter=...`

In the form case with the get parameter and post filter I need to take both type of parameters in the search action. Is this good?

Instead the link will now have all parameters in the `$get` request, but I don't like to build the url with query strings in the template.

What's the best way?

Answer (score 2):

> Use KNP paginator bundle with search action. On search form make the post action to your searchAction in Controller and after sorting data with matching criteria, re-render the page.

```
public function searchAction(Request $request,array $arguments = array())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
            $parameter = $request->get('board_search');
            $boardRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PNCMISDashboardBundle:ExaminationBoards')->loadBoardByName($parameter);
            $boards = $paginator->paginate($boardRepo, $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1), 10);
            return $this->render('PNCMISDashboardBundle:ExaminationBoards/CRUD:index.html.twig', array(
                    'boards'=> $boards,
                )
            );
        }


public function loadBoardByName($name)
    {
        $q = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('boards')
            ->where('upper(boards.name) LIKE upper(:search)')
            ->setParameter('search', '%'.$name.'%')
            ->getQuery()
        ;
        try {
            // The Query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
            // if there is no record matching the criteria.
            $user = $q->getResult();
        } catch (NoResultException $e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Unable to find an board identified by "%s".', $name), null, 0, $e);
        }
        return $user;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to have all the parameters in the query string which will allow the user to bookmark the url or send it in an email.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

1 If you don't need to index (SEO for instance - google bot) the filtered results page, in my opinion you should use AJAX to achieve this.

Routing:

```
search_result:
    pattern: /search
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeExampleBundle:Ajax:searchResult }
    requirements:
        _method:  POST
```

JavaScript (pseudo Code)

```
filterResults() {
    var queryString = $('input#toSearch').val();
    var filters = new Object();
    filters['someKey'] = someVal;
    $.post('/search', {filters: filters, queryString: queryString}, function(data) {
        $('#resultList').html(data);
    });)
}
```

Of course, you should not harcode url '/search'.

Controller:

```
// src/Acme/ExampleBundle/Controller/AjaxController.php
    // ...
    public function searchResultAction()
    {
        $filters = $this->getRequest()->get('filters', array());
        $searchObject = new searchObj(); 
        // or smt like $this->get('service_name'); if you use search object as service
        // you can also use entity manager
        $searchObject->setQueryString($this->getRequest()->get('queryString'));
        $searchObject->setFilters($filters);
        return $this->render('AcmeExampleBundle:Ajax:searchResult.html.twig', array(
            'records' => $searchObject->getResults()
        ));
    }
```

Of course you can return json response, but in my opinion, return ready to inject part of template is simplest to manage

And View:

```
{% for record in records %}
    <div class="record">{{ record.title }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

2 If you wanna index filtred results page you should use user-friendly URLs instead AJAX methods

Routing:

```
search_result:
    pattern: /search/{queryString}/{make}/{model}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeExampleBundle:Ajax:searchResult }
    requirements:
        _method:  GET
```

Controller:

```
// src/Acme/ExampleBundle/Controller/AjaxController.php
    // ...
    public function searchResultAction($queryString, $make, $model)
    {
        $filters = array('make' => $make, 'model' => $model);
        $searchObject = new searchObj(); 
        // or smt like $this->get('service_name'); if you use search object as service
        // you can also use entity manager
        $searchObject->setQueryString($queryString);
        $searchObject->setFilters($filters);
        return $this->render('AcmeExampleBundle:Ajax:searchResult.html.twig', array(
            'records' => $searchObject->getResults()
        ));
    }
```